# Change the default android support

Tags: android, sdk, adt

I am new to android i made a project but every I create a project class it extends actionbaractivity always created, instead of extends activity before it was extends activity every time I created a class, maybe i press something But i dont really know what happned.

This is the result and actionbarActivity is error

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error??. If you don't want `ActionBarActivity` get rid of it and extend `Activity`. If you don't want Fragment also you can get rid of the same.

Comment: in eclipse or android studio? If your min API is <11 I think it defaults to ActionBarActivity

Comment: @Raghunandan I got it to work, but in my  android dependencies i have this error from jars. it is saying that  it is missing in the bin of the library

Comment: @user3444777 i don't understand what you are trying to specify

Comment: @Raghunandan I have a library and I want to use it but in the android dependencies in the build path it is saying that it is missing

Comment: is it library with resources it must be referenced if its not not then you can add the jar to the libs folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up your project to target API < 11 there will be checkboxes for certain support features. ActionBar, GridLayout, Fragments, and NavDrawer. If you check ActionBar the activity that is generated will extend ActionBarActivity (which is the support version of a fragment activity) It may be confusing at first but it's all in the name of supporting older versions of Android with the latest features.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html

Answer (score 0):

If you set your minimum required SDK below 11 it will create the application like this because in API level below 11 there is no ActionBar. The default value is 8. You should set it 14 and then you can change it in your AndroidManifest.xml file.